# $X,Y$ infinite dimensional NLS , not both Banach , then $\exists T \in \mathcal L(X,Y)$ such that $R(T)$ is not closed in $Y$?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X,Y$ be infinite dimensional normed-linear spaces , not both Banach , then does there necessarily exist a continuous linear transformation $T:X \to Y $ such that $range (T)$ is not closed in $Y$ ?

Comment: Do you mean that both spaces are not Banach spaces or that at least one space is not a Banach space?

Comment: @grew : I mean at least one space is not Banach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ the increasing union of a sequence of finite-dimensional spaces $F_n$.  Then $X = \bigcup T^{-1}(F_n)$ with each $T^{-1}(F_n)$ closed.  By the Baire category theorem, some $T^{-1}(F_n)$ has
nonempty interior, and therefore it is all of $X$.  That is, $\text{Range}(T)$ is a subspace of $F_n$, and therefore is closed.

Comment: Y cannot be Banach else by Baire some $F_n$ has non-empty interior in Y, but a finite-dimensional subspace of an infinite-dimensional NLS has empty interior.+1

Comment: @Kevin Dong : But I wanted $Range (T)$ to be not closed ...

Comment: @user228169: Yes, the answer by Kevin shows that what you wanted is false in general. For example if $Y = \Bbb{R}[X]$ (with your favourite norm), then the above answer applies and shows that for every continuous linear operator $T : X \to Y$, the image of $T$ is closed. Note that not **both** of $X,Y$ are Banach. Thus, there does **not** "necessarily exist ...".